# condition for {${b_n}$} to be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Thank JimmyK4542 very much.

Let {${b_n}$}  be a non-negative and bounded real sequence and $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞}\ {b_n}-{b_{n-1}}=0$. With what condition of {${b_n}$} for {${b_n}$}  to be convergent?. Please help me.

Comment: I think that non-negativity will not affect the answer, given that $\{b_n\}$ is bounded. I mean, you could just add a constant to any bounded sequence to make it non-negative, without changing whether it is convergent or not.

Answer (score 1):

If $b_n-b_{n-1}$, for any $n$ big enough, behaves like $\frac{1}{n}$, or $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$, or $\frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))}$, then the limit of $b_{n}-b_{n-1}$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$ is zero, but the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **is not** converging due to the Cauchy's condensation test.  So $\lim_{n\to +\infty}(b_n-b_{n-1})=0$ is not a sufficient condition for the convergence.

However, if for any $n$ big enough we have:
$$|b_n-b_{n-1}|\leq\frac{K}{n\log^2 n}$$
for some positive constant $K$, or the weaker condition:
$$|b_n-b_{n-1}|\leq\frac{K}{n\log n\log^2(\log n)}$$
then the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **is** converging, always in virtue of Cauchy's condensation test.

Assuming that $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and $b_n-b_{n-1}=o(1)$, the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is still free to slowly oscillate between its $\liminf$ and its $\limsup$ - consider, for instance,
$$ b_n = \sin(\log(n+1)).$$